# XAML ListView Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I am having some problems with XAML syntax, I can't undestand what I am doing wrong.

I have a simple window with a ListView control, and a simple ViewModel with an ObservableColletion of items.

The DataContext of the Window is set correctly, but my problem is with the ItemsSource property of the ListView, when I debud the app I can see that the ListView has the DataContext right and that the DataContext has a list with Items.

But the **property ItemsSource is null**, if I set it in code behind it works well.

I have searched for an answer but I can't find one, some post seem to have the same problem but it was always the datacontext.

Here is my code.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="XAMLExamples.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XAMLExamples"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:XAMLExamples.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Ejemplos XAML" Height="350" Width="525" Background="#FF38551F" WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
         >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:TractoViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
            </RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listaAreas}" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ListAreas">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Area" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Area}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Contenedores" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Contenedores}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#**

```
namespace XAMLExamples.ViewModels
{
    public class TractoViewModel 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TractoModel> listaAreas = new ObservableCollection<TractoModel>();
        public TractoViewModel()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                listaAreas.Add(
                    new TractoModel { Area= string.Format("Area {0}",i), Contenedores=i}
                    );
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // With the following line everything is right
            // this.ListAreas.ItemsSource = new XAMLExamples.ViewModels.TractoViewModel().listaAreas;
            // Without the above line ItemsSource is null, even when the DataContext is right
            var iSource = ListAreas.ItemsSource;
            if (iSource == null) return;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the structure of `listaAreas`. Its not only about `how-to-bind` but also about `what-to-bind`.

Comment: i can´t see your datacontext try in mainwindow hits.DataContext = new TractoViewModel();

Answer (score 2):

Data binding in WPF works with public properties, not fields.

So you have to change your `listaAreas` field into a property, e.g. like this:

```
public class TractoViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<TractoModel> listaAreas { get; private set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<TractoModel>();

    ...
}
```

According to a widely accepted C# naming convention, the property name should also begin with an uppercase letter:

```
public ObservableCollection<TractoModel> ListaAreas { get; private set; }
```

Comment: When changing the collection name, don't forget to change it also in the XAML ;)

Comment: you are absolutely right, my problem was that I had a field instead of a property, I just changed the line to:

    public ObservableCollection<TractoModel> ListaAreas { get; set; } =    new ObservableCollection<TractoModel>();

And now I can even see the list in the designer.
I really apreciate your help, it really showed me that I have to think about the basics and how things should work instead of be thinking that something else is wrong. Thanks also to@SeeuD1 @C4u