# MAUI Binding to custom control in a ListView works but binding errors at runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have small Microsoft Maui app which for now I am just deploying to Windows. I am using the Microsoft Community MVVM toolkit.

I have a class named `RoundViewModel` with a couple of properties which represents a round of exercise as part of a longer routine:

```
public partial class RoundViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int exerciseTime;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int restTime;


    internal RoundViewModel(Round r)
    {
        ExerciseTime = r.ExerciseTime;
        restTime = r.RestTime;
    }

}
```

In a ViewModel named `SummaryViewModel` I have a collection of these `RoundViewModel` objects exposed as a property of type `ObservableCollection` as shown below (the collection is initialised in the ViewModel constructor):

```
public partial class SummaryViewModel : ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable
{
    public ObservableCollection<RoundViewModel> Rounds { get; private set; }
```

Finally I want to show within a `ListView` each of the `RoundViewModel` objects in `Rounds` using the following code:

```
  
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Binding Rounds}"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="ViewModels:RoundViewModel">
                    <ViewCell>
                            <VerticalStackLayout>
                                <Controls:RoundView ExerciseTimeBinding="{Binding ExerciseTime}" RestTimeBinding="{Binding RestTime}" />
                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Other questions of this ilk normally describe a problem where data is not seen in the `ListView`.

The problem that I have is that although the code compiles without error and the values in `Rounds`  **are** correctly shown in the `ListView` (via my custom control) I get the following binding errors when I run the application:

`'ExerciseTime' property not found on 'GUI.ViewModels.SummaryViewModel', target property: 'GUI.Controls.RoundView.ExerciseTimeBinding'
'RestTime' property not found on 'GUI.ViewModels.SummaryViewModel', target property: 'GUI.Controls.RoundView.RestTimeBinding'

Other properties on `SummaryViewModel` appear correctly on the page so the binding seems fine except for these run-time binding errors within the `ListView`.

I appreciate that the `ExerciseTime` and `RestTime` properties do not exist on the `SummaryViewModel` which is bound to the page on which the `ListView` appears. However, isn't setting the `ItemsSource` property on the `ListView` enough to set the data context to be used within the `ListView`?

Am I not binding to the custom control correctly? If I remove the bindings on the `Controls:RoundView` element then the binding errors do not occur at run-time but no data is passed to the custom control.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025731/xaml-listview-binding?rq=1) seems to match my code but I seem to be getting run-time binding errors.

---

Edit:

The `SummaryViewModel` has a property called `IntroTime` and I wanted to see if I could bind that within the `ListView`.

When I change the code in the `ListView` to the following

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Binding Rounds}"  >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="ViewModels:RoundViewModel">
                <ViewCell>
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Controls:RoundView ExerciseTime="{Binding IntroTime}" RestTime="{Binding IntroTime}"  />
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

then I get a compilation error stating that `Binding: Property "IntroTime" not found on "GUI.ViewModels.RoundViewModel".`.

So it looks like I have done the right and it follows the solution (as far as I can see) in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126813/adding-xdatatype-to-page-xaml-leads-to-errors-in-listview-datatemplate-properti)

---

Edit:

Updated Visual Studio and made a blank MAUI project. I then imported my code into it. Same error. Feeling that the solution to this problem is not to use Maui!

Comment: Does your custom control have a DataType set?

Comment: I have set the type on the data template where the custom control is used with `<DataTemplate x:DataType="ViewModels:RoundViewModel">`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: According to the error message, the `RoundView`'s binding context is `SummaryViewModel` not RoundViewModel. And for the listview item, it seems you don't have add `x:DataType="ViewModels:RoundViewModel"`, you can try to remove it.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - tried that and it won't compile. I get the error "ExerciseTime" not found on "GUI.ViewModels.SummaryViewModel". Which is correct as it isn't.

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild? Or can your reproduce this on the other platform such as android?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - I had done cleans and rebuilds. I even made a completely new MAUI project and moved my code across to it and got the same error. I seem to have binding errors on all forms (even though data is shown) and the app becomes unresponsive (presumably because so many binding errors are reported). 

I can't get it work on Android. I get an error at start-up not related to binding. It was always my aim to get it working on Windows fully and then to look at other platforms though.

Comment: Can you show the full code about the viewmodel and the `RoundView`? I can't reproduce it without the code.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - I've made the [GitHub](https://github.com/RichyL/GymTimer) repo if you wanted to have a look.

Comment: Did you post a wrong repo link? I didn't see any viewmodel and custom RoundView in the repo you provided.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Sorry mate - it was in the GUI branch. Can you see [this](https://github.com/RichyL/GymTimer/tree/development/GUI)?

Comment: I have cloned it but the error I get is `"" can not be convert to System.Int32`. And why your **GUI project** is target .net 8.0, but the **TimingService project** (reference by the GUI) is target .net 7.0?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - made a [new branch](https://github.com/RichyL/GymTimer/tree/android) to get the app working on Android. If I select a routine on the Home page and then click 'Select Routine' it goes to the Summary page and there are no binding errors. So it looks like for some reason the binding errors only exist on Windows. If I click the 'Edit' button on the Summary screen then I do get binding errors but that is not within the scope of this question.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Thanks for your help though man. Appreciate it.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Now I've fixed some some of the binding issues on Android the app now runs on Windows. So seems like the error reporting on Windows is not a good guide to the real issue. Thanks for the idea to try it on Android though as I would not have tried that unless you had suggested it.

Comment: Glad to know you have resolve it, you can post the solution as an answer and this will help others.